# jQuery - Appending an element within only one container

Tags: jquery, append, each

I have a lot of popups (.popmake-content) and in each one of them, there are two buttons (.slick-arrow) that I want to append to another element (.my_lightbox_navigation) inside the same popup.
I was trying to achieve it like that:

```
jQuery('.popmake-content').each(function(){
    jQuery('.slick-arrow',this).appendTo('.my_lightbox_navigation',this);
});
```

but it appends all of the .slick-arrow elements into .my_lightbox_navigation. How to do this properly?

Comment: Try using closest and find instead of this

Comment: Tried that, edit: no result :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, appendTo hasn't got a context property

```
jQuery('.popmake-content').each(function(i,v){ 
     var box = jQuery(v).find('.my_lightbox_navigation');
    jQuery(v).find('.slick-arrow').appendTo(box);
});
```

```js
jQuery('.popmake-content').each(function(i,v){ 
     var box = jQuery(v).find('.my_lightbox_navigation');
    jQuery(v).find('.slick-arrow').appendTo(box);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popmake-content">
    <button class="slick-arrow"> button 11</button><button class="slick-arrow"> button 12</button>
    <div class="my_lightbox_navigation"></div>
</div>
<div class="popmake-content">
    <button class="slick-arrow"> button 21</button><button class="slick-arrow"> button 22</button>
    <div class="my_lightbox_navigation"></div>
</div>
<div class="popmake-content">
    <button class="slick-arrow"> button 31</button><button class="slick-arrow"> button 32</button>
    <div class="my_lightbox_navigation"></div>
</div>
<div class="popmake-content">
    <button class="slick-arrow"> button 41</button><button class="slick-arrow"> button 42</button>
    <div class="my_lightbox_navigation"></div>
</div>
<div class="popmake-content">
    <button class="slick-arrow"> button 51</button><button class="slick-arrow"> button 52</button>
    <div class="my_lightbox_navigation"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! You are the MVP ;)